# How to set "step" on x-axis in my figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")       
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1.2,1.9,3.1,4.2,4.8]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('OX')
plt.ylabel('OY')
plt.savefig('figure1.png')
plt.close()
```

And it gives me that figure:

[image: my figure]

As you can see, the "step" on axis X is 0.5 but I would like to set it to 1. How to make it?

When I use `plt.xticks(1)`, it gives me errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "overflow.py", line 13, in <module>
    plt.xticks(1)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 998, in xticks
    locs = ax.set_xticks(args[0])   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2064, in set_xticks
    return self.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, minor=minor)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1150, in set_ticks
    if len(ticks) > 1: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I use Python 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

[xticks documentation.](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)

[image: Five x-ticks.]

Answer (score 0):

You can set x-ticks with every other x-tick.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1.2,1.9,3.1,4.2,4.8]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0][1::2]);
```

Another method is to set a tick on each integer position using `MultipleLocator(1)`.

```py
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))
```

[image: img]